# How do I put Javascript in the <head> element of a Coldfusion Model Glue page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, model-glue

I have a Model Glue CFM page `index.cfm` with some JS code that I'd like to execute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#text').height(300);
    });
</script>

<p id="text">This is some text</p>
```

This is being inserted into a CFM template that looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <cfoutput>#viewCollection.getView("body")#</cfoutput>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the relevant part in `ModelGlue.xml`:

```
<event-handler name="page.index">
    <views>
        <include name="body" template="pages/index.cfm"/>
        <include name="main" template="templates/main.cfm"/>
    </views>
</event-handler>
```

Unfortunately, this will stick the Javascript portion directly into the body. Is there a way to put it in the `<head>` tag without having to create a separate CFM file, similar to how the ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor `@section` tag works?

Comment: Why do you say "unfortunately" for having scripts in the body? [Steve Souders recommends](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/05/06/positioning-inline-scripts/) putting scripts at the bottom of the body for performance.

Comment: Because I can't get the script to go where I need it to. Regardless, the same issue applies: how would you stick all your scripts at the bottom of the body?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `<cfhtmlhead>`

For more details, [see the docs here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ae9.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can put `JavaScript` code in head section of `Master.Layout.cfm`. you can also put on body section in page  from where you are calling JavaScript function.